# Finding Memory leaks in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome Tools to figure out cause of memory leaks on my webpage. I have watched following you tube video to learn how to use Profile option in Chrome developers tool to narrow down cause of memory leaks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3ugr9BJqIs

I used the 3 step snapshot view approach to pinpoint an object that is retained between snapshot 1 and snapshot 3. When i clicked on the node, that is not highlighted in yellow, in the comparison window, i get following object tree. As per the video i can ignore any objects in grey (the system objects) and ones in Yellow background as they are reachable by Javascript and will be garbage collected. Based on that information, i cannot figure out why the object is still retained in the memory between snapshot 1 and snapshot3. The highlighted row(in blue background) is also highlighted in yellow which means it can be ignored that row also.[image]

Any help or pointer greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Could you tell me what are snapshots 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: Thanks Dan, based on the attached image, is there a node that i can explore to figure out what is causing this particular instance of my object not be deleted from the memory? There are too many objects under the collapsed nodes. When i expanded one of the collapsed node, it showed me close to 800+objects. I am not sure if i should be even investigating that node. Is there a rule of thumb that i can use to ignore certain nodes? Would it be ok to assume that node for example: instance in system / Context @3142501 in above image won't have any reference that would keep this instance in memory.

Comment: Thanks Spencer. The webform has lots of controls and each snapshot is close to 20+MB. I am not sure how i can attach or share those snapshots with you. I am seeking for guidance as to how to avoid unnecessary investigation of nodes shown in the tool. What kind of nodes would be ok to be ignored or what shall i be looking in the delta snaphot to troubleshoot the cause of memory leaks.

Comment: Generally you only want to look for data that is likely to be a memory leak. Some for example are easy to tell will not cause problems, others generally object creations will, again this is also JavaScript: such that it's garbage collector can help with basic problems that are easily detectable. There is no specific way to look, it depends entirely on how you coded your program. Look through your code and identify items that could case memory leak problems. Others that are obvious will not do not need to be looked at in the developer tool (you must be sure).

Comment: Here is what i found while observing memory leaks in my code. Begin with the objects that are created by you. Once you take a heap snaphot, try to filter the objects that are created by you and then study the object retaining tree. For the image in my post, I found that the cause of memory leak in my code was object _onSubmitStatements. I was creating that object and adding it to PageRequestManager but was not releasing it correctly in dispose method. This might not work for everybody but is a good place to start.